# What is the best way to put logs on standard output generated by an infinite loop?

Tags: terminal, memory-leaks, infinite-loop, ada

I am working on a (multi) client - server environment using PolyORB (DSA personality) by Adacore.

I have one shared passive partition which basically contains a protected type (array) which gets updated by the server with info coming from the clients every second, on a non-stop basis.

I have created a very simple main unit with an infinite loop just to monitor the content of that array.

As expected, printing out the rows of the array every second on the standard output is consuming the memory of the system.

I would like to avoid, if possible, the solution of printing out the info on a file, and run a tail -f command. I would not like to mess around with the disk, the number of clients now is limited but it is expected to grow and performance might get compromised.

On the other hand, I have tried through scripting to kill the monitor and launch it again, but somehow it does seem to work only once. I killed it, and then launched again (OK), then kill it again and the launched (not OK).

Is there a good way to print out a lot of info on the standard output using and infinite loop and not running out of memory?

I have checked there is no other issue causing the memory leak, if no info is printed out on the terminal, there is no problem with the memory.

This is the code of that monitor main unit

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Shared_Table;
with GNAT.OS_Lib;

procedure monitor is

 -- Variables to run linux command clear
 ARGUMENTS : GNAT.OS_Lib.Argument_List := (1 => new String'(""));
 RESULT : Boolean := False;

begin

   loop

         -- Clearing the terminal after writing the content of the table.

         GNAT.OS_Lib.Spawn (Program_Name => "/usr/bin/clear",
                            Args         => ARGUMENTS,
                            Success      => RESULT);

         -- Printing out the content of the table on the standard output.

         Shared_Table.Visualize_Table (Shared_Table.Obtain_Table);

         delay 1.0;

   end loop;  

end monitor;
```

Thanks!

Here it is the code of the procudure to print out the rows of the array which is likely to be causing the memory leak.

```
procedure Visualize_Table (Shared_Table : in Shared_Table_Type) is
      
      -- Very big varibale containing adaptation data in a simple linked list.
      Adaptation_Data : Adaptation.Track_List.List;
      
      -- Segment type is a record. One of the components being a simple linked list of items.
      Segment_Aux : Segment.Segment_Type;

      -- Track Type is a record. One of the components being a simple linked list of segments.
      Track_Aux : Track.Track_Type;
      
      Number_of_items : Natural range 1 .. 3 := 1;
   
   begin
      
      -- Load adaptation data.
      Adaptation.Generate_Track_List (Adaptation_Data);
      
      -- Visualize header.
      Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line (" +-----------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------------+");
      Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line (" | xxxxxxxxx |          xxxxxxxxxxxx           | # Items |          xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        |  xxxxxxxxx  |");
      Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line (" +-----------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------------+");
      
      for I in 1 .. Number_of_clients loop
            
         -- Visualize first two columns.
         Ada.Text_Io.Put (" | " & Shared_Table(I).First_Row & "  | ");
         Ada.Text_Io.Put (Shared_Table(I).Second_Row & "| ");
            
         -- Initialize auxiliar variables..
         Track.Initialize_Track (Track_Aux);
         Segment.Initizalize (Segment_Aux);

         Track.Set_Id (Id    => Shared_Table(I).Track_Id,
                       Track => Track_Aux);
         
         Segment.Set_Position (Position => Shared_Table(I).Position,
                               Segment  => Segment_Aux);
            
         Number_of_items := 
           Segment.List_of_items.Obtain_Number 
             (Segment.Obtain_List_of_items 
                (Track.List_of_segments.Find_Element 
                   (Element => Segment_Aux,
                    List    => Track.Obtain_Segment_List (Adaptation.Track_List.Find_Element (Element => Track_Aux,
                                                                                              List    => Adaptation_Data)))));
            
         Ada.Text_Io.Put (" |");

         Ada.Text_Io.Put ("    X : ");
         Ada.Integer_Text_Io.Put (Item => Shared_Table(I).Position_X,
                                  Width => 7);
         Ada.Text_Io.Put ("  Y : ");
         Ada.Integer_Text_Io.Put (Item => Shared_Table(I).Position_Y,
                                  Width => 7);
         Ada.Text_Io.Put ("     |");

         Ada.Integer_Text_Io.Put (Item => Shared_Table(I).Last_Row,
                                  Width => 3);
         Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line ("          |");
            
         Ada.Text_Io.Put_Line 
           (" +-----------+---------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+-------------+");
         
      end loop;
      
   end Visualize_Table;
```

My understanding is that the variables life should end when the procedure finishes printing out the rows of the array, and the memory used by them should then be free, but given some of the variables are linked list (using access types), that may not be the case, is that possible?

This is part of the log obtained by usgin valgrind

```
==17190== 61,799,120 (7,774,208 direct, 54,024,912 indirect) bytes in 60,736 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 816 of 816
==17190==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17190==    by 0x68D12E: __gnat_malloc (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
==17190==    by 0x691C7C: system__pool_global__allocate (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
==17190==    by 0x4CFD16: adaptation__track_list__insert_element (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
==17190==    by 0x4D6028: adaptation__generate_track_list (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
==17190==    by 0x4D991C: shared_table__visualize_table (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
==17190==    by 0x4DB9FE: _ada_monitor (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
==17190==    by 0x47926F: partition___elabb (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
==17190==    by 0x47BA56: adainit (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
==17190==    by 0x47BAC1: main (in /home/hector/ITS/distributed/src/monitor)
```

I can see some other memory leaks all of the ultimately pointing to the instantiation of the procedure to insert new elements in a simple linked list.

This is the code of the generic package.

```
   procedure Insert_Element (Element : in Type_Element;
                             List : in out Type_List) is
    
      Pointer_to_Cell : Type_Pointer_to_Cell := new Type_Cell'(Record_Element => Element,
                                                               Record_Pointer => List.Record_Initial_Cell);
      
   begin
      
      if List.Record_Number_of_elements <= Max_Number_of_elements then
         
         List.Record_Initial_Cell := Pointer_to_Cell;
         List.Record_Number_of_elements := List.Record_Number_of_elements + 1;
         
      else
         
         raise List_Full_Exception;
         
      end if;

   end Insert_Element;
```

How can I deallocate the memory used by *Adaptation_Data* once I do not need it anymore?

Comment: Not a PolyORB expert, just some questions to clarify. It's not entirely clear how the monitor program fails the second time you start it. Does it report some memory error or does it just hang? Do you see memory consumption run out-of-control? Does it actually rejoin/reconnect again to the (DSA) program and receive new data? Does the remaining part of the DSA application still run properly after you kill the monitor program? Can you give some indication of how much lines/characters are being printed to the output per loop iteration to give an idea of why memory might become a problem?

Comment: The second time I try to restart the monitor it looks like it just hangs, nothing is printed out on the standard output. Memory is definitely not out of control. The sequence would be like this, first run (OK), second run (OK) subsequents runs (not OK). The rest of the DSA application keeps running smoothly after I kill the monitor. On every iteration about no more than 7 lines of text and no more than 107 characters per line are printed.

Comment: How do you synchronize access to `Shared_Table`?

Comment: What happens if you change the call to `Spawn` to `Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (Spacing => 100);`?

Comment: @trashgod The object accessed, the array, is an Ada protected type. When I call the function to obtain the array, I actually use a function of the protected object itself, which guarantees the data is not being written while I access it. In other words, there is no synchronization

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter I have changed the call to Spawn to New Line, now, as expected the rows of the array appear at the bottom of the terminal. The memory consumption I have seen (5 iterations) is slightly higher than the one with the call to Spawn. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: Why are you printing the entire array at once instead of writing each line as it is written to the protected object? Your program does provide synchronization by ensuring the function to read the array locks out any writes to the array during the read.

Comment: The array can be implemented as a circular buffer. Each read can be done using an entry that extracts the oldest message. The consuming task simply prints the string read from the buffer. The buffer read entry suspends if there is no data in the buffer. The writer entry suspends when the buffer is full.

Comment: Since using `New_Line` doesn't significantly change memory use, we can conclude that your memory leak is in `Shared_Table`. As we have not seen that, we can't help with it.

Comment: @JimRogers Yes, the function reading the array locks the array and it cannot be modified until is unlocked. When I said before there is no synchronization what I meant is that there is nothing in my code to syncrhonize write/read operations, that is done through the protected type interface, that is the purpose of using protected types. I think it may be worthy to try the circular buffer option, it will make the code more complicated but it may work.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter The thing is that if I do not print out the array at all, that is, I just obtain every second the complete array and then do nothing, there is no memory leak at all. I ran an iteration for 24 hours and the process monitor did not even appear when running top to be one of the top 30 process in terms of memory consumption in my system. That is why I think, and I kind of expected that, the memory leak seems to be due to printing out the array on the terminal continously.

Comment: If you obtain the array but do nothing with it, it's possible the compiler can optimize it away. If that's not the case, you print the array using an operation of `Shared_Table`, and since we have not seen that, we can't help with it.

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter I am going to get into the procedure which prints the array and modify it to just print the header, (the name of the field for every column), that is, no variables whatsoever involved, if the memory consuption gets reduced I will probably post the code for help. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter Thanks for the hint. Yesterday night I ran a simulation in which the procedure to visualize the output did not use any variable whatsoever and only printed data obtained from the array directly and it ran smoothly the whole night, no memory leak at all. I am going to post the code (I would try to simplify it so it is clear to everybody what it does). Thanks.

Comment: We still lack enough information to identify a memory leak, but my first guess would be to look at the "simple linked lists". I note that you repeatedly do `Obtain_Segment_List` and `Obtain_List_of_items`, which might also bear looking into. I note that you have the illegal identifier `_First_Row` in your posted code, so clearly it is not your actual code.

Comment: My code is writte in Spanish, that is a literal translation

Comment: After running valgrind it is for sure thar there is a big memory leak in the way Adaptation_Data variable is handled

Answer (score 1):

A generic protected object using a circular buffer can look like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Generic Bounded Protected Queue
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

generic
   type Element_Type is private;
   type Queue_Index is mod <>;
package Generic_Protected_Bounded_Queue is
   type Buffer is array (Queue_Index) of Element_Type;

   protected type Queue is
      function Capacity return Natural;
      function Is_Full return Boolean;
      function Is_Empty return Boolean;
      entry Enqueue (Value : in Element_Type);
      entry Dequeue (Value : out Element_Type);
      procedure Clear;
   private
      Buf   : Buffer;
      Head  : Queue_Index := 0;
      Tail  : Queue_Index := 0;
      Count : Natural     := 0;
   end Queue;

end Generic_Protected_Bounded_Queue;
```

The corresponding body is:

```
package body Generic_Protected_Bounded_Queue is

   -----------
   -- Queue --
   -----------

   protected body Queue is

      --------------
      -- Capacity --
      --------------

      function Capacity return Natural is
      begin
         return Buf'Length;
      end Capacity;

      -------------
      -- Is_Full --
      -------------

      function Is_Full return Boolean is
      begin
         return Buf'Length = Count;
      end Is_Full;

      --------------
      -- Is_Empty --
      --------------

      function Is_Empty return Boolean is
      begin
         return Count = 0;
      end Is_Empty;

      -------------
      -- Enqueue --
      -------------

      entry Enqueue (Value : in Element_Type) when Count < Buf'Length is
      begin
         Buf (Tail) := Value;
         Tail       := Tail + 1;
         Count      := Count + 1;
      end Enqueue;

      -------------
      -- Dequeue --
      -------------

      entry Dequeue (Value : out Element_Type) when Count > 0 is
      begin
         Value := Buf (Head);
         Head  := Head + 1;
         Count := Count - 1;
      end Dequeue;

      -----------
      -- Clear --
      -----------

      procedure Clear is
      begin
         Head  := 0;
         Tail  := 0;
         Count := 0;
      end Clear;

   end Queue;

end Generic_Protected_Bounded_Queue;
```

When using this approach the consuming task does not need a one second timer to output the data. It only needs to print a line of text as soon as it arrives in the protected object buffer. The printing of data then becomes an event-based activity and not a timer-based activity.

Hi Jim, this the code for the task. I hope it helps

```
task Visualize_Data;
   
   task body Visualize_Data is
      
      Arguments : GNAT.OS_Lib.Argument_List := (1 => new String'(""));
      Result  : Boolean := False;

   begin
      
      loop
         
         if Shared_Table.Obtain_Rows > 0 then
            
            Shared_Table.Visualize_Header;

            for I in 1 .. Shared_Table.Obtain_Rows loop
            
               declare
           
                  Row : Shared_Table.Row;
         
               begin
         
                  Bounded_Buffer.Queue.Dequeue (Row);
                  Shared_Table.Visualize_Row (Row);
                  
               end;

            end loop;
                  
            
            GNAT.OS_Lib.Spawn (Program_Name => "/usr/bin/clear",
                               Args                  => Argument,
                               Success             => Result);
            
         end if;
         
      end loop;
      
   end Visualize_Data;
```

Of course, the task uses a lot of CPU resources because of the outer loop. That loop performs a polling operation rather than waiting for data to be available. The shared table should be implemented as a bounded buffer. The reading task will then suspend when the buffer is empty and read data only when it is available.

See the following example using the bounded queue package:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with generic_protected_bounded_queue;

procedure Main is
   type Index_T is mod 10;
   package int_queue is new generic_protected_bounded_queue(Element_Type => Integer,
                                                            Queue_Index  => Index_T);
   use int_queue;

   The_Queue : Queue;

   task producer;
   task body producer is
   begin
      Put_Line("Producer started.");
      for Num in 1..20 loop
         The_Queue.Enqueue(Num);
         Put_Line("Enqueued" & Num'Image);
      end loop;
      Put_Line("Producer terminating.");
   end Producer;

   task consumer;
   task body consumer is
      Num : Integer;
   begin
      Put_Line("Consumer started.");
      for Val in 11..30 loop
         The_Queue.Dequeue(Num);
         Put_Line("Dequeued" & Num'Image);
      end loop;
      Put_Line("Consumer terminating.");
   end Consumer;

begin
   null;
end Main;
```

Comment: It is worth trying. At least it gives me a new path to explore. I will post here the result once I can test it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have just finished testing this approach and I am afraid the memory consumption is much higher (almost 3 times higher). I should have pointed out that clients send updated information to the server every second.

Comment: Can you show the code for your logging task? Once per second is very slow. The task should suspend until data is read in the buffer. Once the data is ready the task should read the data, log it, and then try to read the buffer again. For most of the 1 second the logging task should be suspended, using no CPU.

Comment: Shared_Table is defined within a Shared_Passive package, only entryless protected types are avilable. I need data to be accessed in a robust way by different partitions.

Comment: Whoever designed Shared_Table did a poor job.

Comment: Well, thats is the Ada DSA design. https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/polyorb/html/polyorb_ug/Ada_Distributed_Systems_Annex_(DSA).html

Comment: It appears you overlooked the Rate_Type parameters of the protected procedures shown in the example in section 8.1.6.2 of your link above.

Comment: Do you mean the external synchronization? That would end up making the code more complicated. Shared_Table was designed to be accessed through protected procedures and funtions so no external synchronization was required. Anyway, as per the comments above, the problem of the memory leak is not in the way Shared_Table is accessed or the way the information in the table is printed out. It has to do with simple linked lists being used.

Comment: If the lists are the problem, I presume you are not using a list from`Ada.Containers`. Why not?